# Creating a ZIP file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, jszip

```
async acquistoMultiplo(decoded, datiAcquisto){

    const utente = await Database.utente.findOne({where: { id_utente: decoded.id_utente }});
    if( ! utente) return [404, 'ERRORE: utente [' + decoded.id_utente + '] non trovato'];
    
    if(utente.credito<datiAcquisto.length) return [401, 'ERRORE: credito residuo insufficiente'];

    const zip = new JSZip();
    
    for(let i = 0; i < datiAcquisto.length; i++){
      let prodotto = await Database.prodotto.findOne({where: { id_prodotto: datiAcquisto[i].id_prodotto, disponibile: true}});
      if(! prodotto) return [404, 'ERRORE: prodotto [' + datiAcquisto[i].id_prodotto + '] non trovato o momentaneamente non disponibile!'];

      const fileFS = fs.readFileSync(prodotto.link);
      zip.file(prodotto.link, fileFS);
    }
      
    const dataAcquisto = getDataCorrente();

    for(let i = 0; i < datiAcquisto.length; i++){

      const acquistoPresente = await Database.acquisto.findOne({where: {utente: utente.id_utente, prodotto: datiAcquisto[i].id_prodotto}});
      if( ! acquistoPresente)  {
        const acquistoSalvato = await Database.acquisto.create({ utente: utente.id_utente, prodotto: datiAcquisto[i].id_prodotto, data_acquisto: dataAcquisto, originale: true});
        if( ! acquistoSalvato) return [500, 'ERRORE SERVER: impossibile salvare l\'acquisto'];
      } else {
        const acquistoSalvato = await Database.acquisto.create({ utente: utente.id_utente, prodotto: datiAcquisto[i].id_prodotto, data_acquisto: dataAcquisto, originale: false});
        if( ! acquistoSalvato) return [500, 'ERRORE SERVER: impossibile salvare l\'acquisto'];
      }
    }

    // aggiorna credito residuo dell'utente
    const creditoResiduo = utente.credito-datiAcquisto.length;
    const creditoAggiornato = await Database.utente.update({ credito: creditoResiduo }, {
        where: {
          id_utente: utente.id_utente
        }
      });
    if( ! creditoAggiornato) return [500, 'ERRORE SERVER: impossibile aggiornare il credito residuo'];
    
    zip.generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
       .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./files/out.zip'))
       .on('finish', function(){
            console.log('file zip creato');
    });


    zip
      .generateInternalStream({type:"uint8array"})
      .accumulate(function updateCallback(metadata) {
          // metadata contains for example currentFile and percent, see the generateInternalStream doc.
      }).then(function (data) {
          // data contains here the complete zip file as a uint8array (the type asked in generateInternalStream)
          fs.createWriteStream('./files/out.zip');
      });



    return ['./files/out.zip'];
  }
```

This is my file. I am not able to let the **program wait to finish the creation of the zip file** before to execute the return function.
*What I am doing wrong? I know that this i an async function that create the zip file. What can I do?*
I need help to fix this problem. I dont know what i need to write more

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a promise and await the the process of zip file creation before returning:

```html
//...

await (() =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    zip
      .generateNodeStream({ type: "nodebuffer", streamFiles: true })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./files/out.zip"))
      .on("finish", function () {
        console.log("file zip creato");

        resolve();
      });
  }))();
  
return ['./files/out.zip'];
```